# flutter app crashed on ios simulator when call firestore query

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter application that uses firestore as database , **app works on android perfectly**.
but on the ios simulator when call a firestore query app immediately crashed, I made my query too simple but this problem exists yet.
my query line:

```
userCollection.doc("5m1K6U5FCrSqq2cBagywjpTWfDJ3").update({"age":60});
```

and after the crash Xcode log is

```
Runner[8031:184013] -[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8a6d9fa0
2023-06-25 09:22:30.187535-0700 Runner[8031:184013] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x7fff8a6d9fa0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20405604 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a4a45 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204145ba +[NSObject(NSObject) 
instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20409bbf ___forwarding___ + 1471
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040bd48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Runner                              0x0000000106d6c1fe -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader 
FIRFirestoreSettings] + 318
6   Runner                              0x0000000106d6becd -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader 
readValueOfType:] + 1517
7   Flutter                             0x000000011595a055 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 48
8   Runner                              0x0000000106d6e9d4 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader 
FIRFirestore] + 116
9   Runner                              0x0000000106d6be89 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader 
readValueOfType:] + 1449
10  Flutter                             0x000000011595a055 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 48
11  Flutter                             0x000000011595a6ff 
FlutterStandardCodecHelperReadValueOfType + 653
12  Runner                              0x0000000106d6bf97 -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader 
readValueOfType:] + 1719
13  Flutter                             0x000000011595a055 _ZL9ReadValuePKv + 48
14  Flutter                             0x0000000115958be8 -[FlutterStandardMethodCodec 
decodeMethodCall:] + 94
15  Flutter                             0x0000000115955ccc __45-[FlutterMethodChannel 
setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 55


libc++abi: **terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Deve 
 loper/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/unitedstar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gtslupndqqoxmxbfqydieffxbzro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/unitedstar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- 
gtslupndqqoxmxbfqydieffxbzro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull 
intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8a6d9fa0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 802.6.1 - Device: iPhone 12 (89A9ED33-F3F5-4375-95AC-EC0F62785D6D) - Runtime: 
iOS 15.5 (19F70) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
(lldb)
```

note to this line
**terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

I checked that all plugins about firebase uses last version
i use these plugins

```
firebase_core: ^2.14.0
firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.8.1
firebase_storage: ^11.1.0
```

need to tell you that on mac os before running the project I upgrade the flutter. you can consider it

Comment: Are you sure that the document exists and that the current user has permission to read it? The crash says you tried to get the current integer value of `NULL`.  Split your line in two - First get the document reference and verify that the document exists.  If so, then perform the update

Comment: All permissions are true in firestore. Before this query i tried to add a document to this collection by the Set function but. I got current error. Consider that this code currently works on android

Comment: I would suggest that you break the line in two, fetch the document and verify that it can be read. Set a breakpoint and use the debugger.  The crash says that an attempt was made to call `intValue` on an `NSNull` object.

Comment: I tried that but got the previous error.
it shows a red line in line `@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate { `in AppDelegate.swift file that says `==Thread1: singnal SIGABRT`

my current code is `var data= await users.doc("O6RK3cDJdNOjVq5MEjOznlqBARp2").get();` that the document exist in firestore.

Comment: Did you single step with the debugger?  Which operation caused the exception? Did you try and fetch the document and check its properties? on iOS runtime exceptions cannot be caught; Something you are doing is causing the native Firebase code to try and read the integer value of `NSNull`.

Comment: yes I told you which operation coused this exception , but I dont know ios native, i need another solution like downgrade firestore dependency or ....

Comment: Use the Flutter debugger. You don't need to get into the native code.  You need to make sure that you don't pass null to the native code. Are you using Null Safety in your flutter app?  If `users.doc("O6RK3cDJdNOjVq5MEjOznlqBARp2").get()` is crashing then either that document doesn't exist or the current user doesn't have permission to read it or even that the `users` collection isn't valid.

Comment: document and collections exists.

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
} this is firestore rules . Users has all permissions

Comment: I can't tell you any more than your code tried to access the integer value of `NSNull`.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by creating a new Flutter project, and connect it to the previous Firestore database, and replacing codes from the previous project with the new project,
but I could not find the problem.
but solved by this solution